# How to construct HighCharts data series to match returned Json via ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, highcharts

I'm trying to construct an Highchart with a JSON returned from my .NET controller. The data is formatted in the following way (in the controller):

```
var data = new
        {
             sentiment = new[]
             {
              new { value = "Positive", data = positiveScore.ToString() },
              new { value = "Negative", data = negativeScore.ToString() },
              new { value = "Neutral", data = neutralScore.ToString() }
            }
        };

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The data I'm receiving is the following:

[image: Data structure]

My Highchart is constructed in the following way:

```
function sentimentAnalysisData(data)
//$(document).ready(function ()
{
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie',
        renderTo: 'highchart'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Sentiment Analysis'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{data}]


    //});
})
};
```

The `data` parameter passed to my function is actually the data you can see in the image I provided. I had a GET request via an ajax call, where I retrieved the data, then, in the "on success" callback I'm calling this function which will construct the chart.

My problem is the following: the Highchart is generated, I can see it on my front end, but since my data is passed in a wrong way to the `series` field, the chart body is actually empty, with no data to show. I've tried to generate it on the way, I also tried to loop through the object, parse it in two arrays and use those arrays (one for the description string and one for value) but I'm missing something. Any helpful thoughts?

Comment: hi , check http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-basic/  there is no `value` and `data` key inside series object.Instead there is `name` and `y` key

Comment: @Patata you are right,I don't realize how I missed that.Thanks for pointing this out,I was able to solve my problem after that

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem in the following way:

I changed the way I constructed my JSON in order to match the pie chart structure in which I had a name and a value part (the name part must be noted as "name", and the value as "y")

```
 var data = new[]
            {
              new { name = "Positive", y = positiveScore },
              new { name = "Negative", y = negativeScore },
              new { name = "Neutral" , y = neutralScore }

            };

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In this way I got the exact structure I was looking for in the first place. Also, I eliminated the `.toString()` from the y, since Highchart expects a numeric value, not a string. If you omit this part, you'll get the following error:

> String value sent to series.data, expected Number his happens if you
>   pass in a string as a data point